Bayes theorem for events that happen in a particular order
I'm trying to understand how we can use Bayes theorem to calculate probabilities for events that occur in a specific order. I'll give an example: suppose I have a dream PhD programme I want to get into (let's say, PhD in Stats @ University A). Now, I need to first do a Master's degree and I have offers from three Universities: B, C, and D. I want take the Master's programme which maximises my chances of getting into the PhD programme at University A. So, setting these events:

B, C, and D: attending University B/C/D for MSc programme.
A: being accepted into the PhD programme at University A.

So, I want to find out which conditional probability is the largest. For example, $P(A|B)$. Now, to do this, we can use Bayes' theorem. However, the aspect that confuses me, is what would $P(B|A)$ be? Event B does not depend on event A, because event A can not occur without one of B,C, or D first happening.

From my understanding, you can obtain $P(B|A)$ using Bayes theorem, given that $P(A|B)$ is your likelihood and getting into B, C or D are disjoint events. But calculating $P(A|B)$ might require some additional info like what are the rates of admission to PhD programme in A given that the student passed from B.

$P(B \mid A)$ might be read as representing the answer to "Just knowing an individual is accepted into the PhD programme at University A, what is the probability they previously attended the MSc programme at University B?"  This is not supposed to be causal and so does not need to be sequential.

Let's look at a table with 900 students from that graduated last year at schools B,C,D, and did or did not enter the PhD program at school A.
    !A    A
B  500   15
C  250   30
D  100    5

With this table you can compute all sorts of frequencies like P(B|A) = 15/50, P(A|B) = 15/515, P(A) = 50/900, P(B) = 515/900. And they relate with each other according to Bayes' rule.

So event B does not need to depend on A in a direct causal relationship, A doesn't have to cause B. But we can still think about the statistical relationship. Among A, how many have B as well?

So, I want to find out which conditional probability is the largest

You wouldn't do this so much with Bayes rule. You do have the relationship P(A|B) = P(B|A) P(A)/P(B} but the values in the right side are not known for this practical problem.
The typical situation for applying Bayes' rule is when we have some (unknown) distribution parameter, and data, and we know the likelihood, P(data|parameter), the distribution of the data based on the parameter.
In your case this unknown distribution parameter is the value p = P(A|B), and not the terms A or B. You estimate it by sampling several B and count the frequency of A among them.

I like your example for illustrating the OPs question. But I would like to remark that your P-s are not probabilities but are ratio's (or frequencies). In my opinion, this is not a Bayesian problem.

@RomkeBontekoe I called them frequencies instead of probabilities on purpose. If one insists one could make probabilities out of them by considering a random draw out of those 900 students. But indeed, it is still different from the practical problem statement "So, I want to find out which conditional probability is the largest" which is more about a hypothetical theoretical distribution, of which those 900 students are only a single sample. But anyways the relationship P(A|B) = P(B|A) P(A)/P(B) holds for both cases.

@RomkeBontekoe A probability is a ratio. P(A|B) is the ratio of (the probability mass of A) to (the probability mass of A&B).

"P(B) = 515/900" No, P(B) is the number of students who graduated from B divided by the total number of students.

@Acccumulation the number of students who graduated from B = 515, the total number of students = 900
